# "Temporary Internet Files" folder vs "Content.IE5" subfolder

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have two web apps, one asp-based and one asp.net based.  When accessing them through IE6 (don't ask, it's required), the temp files for the asp-based one are stored at "C:\Documents and Settings[UserName]\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files", while the asp.net-based ones are stored at "C:\Documents and Settings\jmaddre\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5".  I'm having security issues with accessing the "Content.IE5" folder, so wondering if I might change the location of those files to the "Temporary Internet Files" root folder.

My question is, is it possible to make that change?  And what causes some temp files to be stored in the root folder, but others in the "Content.IE5" subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the location of the temporary internet files folder, but you cannot prevent the browser wanting to create the Content.IE5 subfolder.

As to why some of the cached files may not be stored in the Content.IE5 folder, Microsoft has not provided that information.

Answer (score 1):

All content downloaded by IE itself should be within randomly named subfolders of the Content.IE5 subfolder. The root folder itself *should* not contain any files other than index.dat, but some software will store files in the root folder. The reason for doing so is that files inside the root of \Temporary Internet Files\ or any child folder are automatically treated as having originated from the Internet Zone, which is used by Local Machine Lockdown.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx